# Как подружить Sequelize с существующей таблицой в MSSQL?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Есть БД отдельной программы которая используют БД MSSQL на локальном компьютере.
Планируется, что данные из БД будут только читаться.
Как мне опредилить модель Sequelize с таблицами в БД, если в некоторых таблицах поля имеют тип данных "money" который я не могу описать в модели Sequelize?